Mark a method as "requires override" in Swift?
I want to have something like
class Parent {
   @mustBeOverridden
   func overrideThis(_ s: Source) -> Target {
       // does not do anything, i.e. it is "abstract"
   }
}

class Child1: Parent {
} // -> throws a compilation error, because overrideThis is not overridden.

class Child2: Parent {
    override
    func overrideThis(_ s: Source) -> Target {
        // transform s 
    }
} // -> Compiles

I suppose "the swifty way" would be something like
protocol IParent {
    func overrideThis(_ s: Source) -> Target
}

class ParentClass {
}

typealias Parent = ParentClass & IParent

class Child: Parent {
    func overrideThis(_ s: Source) -> Target {
        // transform s 
    }
}

Is what I want feasible (how?), or should I always go with the second option?
The problem with the second option for me is: what if the Parent conforms to a protocol, but does not implement all methods required in it, because I want subclasses to implement some specific functionalities?

Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/36472186/476…?

@deceze A bit, maybe. But that is a very old question, basically from Swift's infancy. Maybe something has changed by now?

@CocoaNut not much has changed with this regard since the early days of Swift - Swift still has no support for abstract classes, so your suggested approach still doesn't work.
